# Amount or number of books

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality-in-context, countability

While writing an essay, I discovered that my MacBook Ru-En dictionary suggests using *amount* speaking about books:

[image]

So, that is what I have in my text:

> I state again that reading a lot has big advantages: while reading we develop our imagination and vocabulary and it is strongly connected with **the amount of books**.

On the other hand, there is an ambiguous information [given](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-huge-amount-of-books.1566584/) on another site.

Could you please explain: is it correct to use the word *amount* in relation to books?

Comment: "we have any amount of books" sounds strange and non-fluent to this US English speaker.

Comment: Stangdon: agreed. We have any amount of bound and printed material; we have any number of books.

Comment: Side note: There's a difference between an _example_ usage in a dictionary, and a _recommended_ usage in a dictionary. I wouldn't go so far as to say that this dictionary is "recommending" the word _amount_ over _number_ in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "number" of items refers to something you can count. You can count books, so it's "a number of books." This answers the question, How many?

Amount refers to something you can't count. Abstract concepts cannot be counted. You have a large amount of determination, for example. Amount answers the question, How much?

Sometimes it's tricky to determine which to use. Liquid is not something you can count, but you could count the number of measurements. For example, I cannot tell you "how many" water I have (because that doesn't mean anything, since I can't count it), but I can tell you how many gallons of water I have.

Answer (score 1):

I would say in your example

> it is strongly connected with **the amount of books**.

does not work, since a person can only read a *finite* number of books.

Where your phrase might be possible is

> **The amount of books** that they have in the library is ginormous.

implying an *uncountable* number of books.

[image]

Comment: _The [**number**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+number+of+books%2Cthe+amount+of+books&year_start=1945&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5) of books that they have in the library_ still sounds better to me, whether its "ginormously uncountable" or not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "number" of books in the library is ginormous is correct. There may be a lot of books there but they can be counted.