# Is "amount of cars" better than "number of cars" in my sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Does **amount** works better than **number** here? No one will count the number of cars in a parking lot. They won't know the number of cars there. So I wonder if "amount" is better.

> Big-box stores hurt the environment. If one looks at the extensive parking lots of these stores, one will
> know the **amount** of private cars they attract.

Comment: It doesn't. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170706/amount-or-number-of-books).

Comment: @KateBunting, but no one will count the number of cars parked in a parking lot. They won't know the number of cars there. So I wonder if it's better to say that one will know the amount of cars.

Comment: Nevertheless, _car_ is a countable noun.

Comment: @newbieforever Something you *can* count, not something you *will* count. Note that many English speakers could indeed say "amount" here -- and before "books" in the other question. But they would be frowned upon by editors and anyone who compares it to "number". Hence it's possible to hear, but certainly not (as your question puts it) better.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I don't know why. I just don't like the sound of "number" here. Is "volume of private cars" better?

Comment: Grammar/language aside, the factual claim is incorrect. Shopping malls most certainly count the number of cars that use the facility. Each store will also count footfall [the number of people who cross their threshold every day.] This is commonplace data-collection these days.